# a question on Brauer groups and trivialised Azumaya algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, brauer-groups

If an Azumaya algebra $A$ on a scheme $X$ is trivialised by $A = \mathcal{End}(\mathcal{O})$, $\mathcal{O}$ locally free on $X$, why is $\mathcal{O}$ uniquely determined up to tensoring with a line bundle?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easier answer. If $A=End_R(E)\cong End_R(F)$ with center a commutative ring $R$, then $F$ is an $End(E)$ module via the isomorphism. Now Morita theory says that $L:=Hom_A(E,F)$ is a rank 1 projective module over $R$ which you can check by localizing at any prime ideal and computing in matrices. Moreover $E\otimes_R L\to F$ is similarly an isomorphism. This argument generally goes under the name of the Skolem-Noether theorem.

Answer (score 4):

One way to see this is to look at the sequence in cohomology

> $H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m) \to H^1(X,\mathbf{GL}_n) \to H^1(X,\mathbf{PGL}_n) \to \mathbf{Br} X$

which comes from the obvious short exact sequence of algebraic groups.  Now $H^1(X,\mathbf{PGL}_n)$ classifies Azumaya algebras on $X$ of degree $n$.  The trivial ones are those in the image of $H^1(X,\mathbf{GL}_n)$, which classifies vector bundles of rank $n$; the trick is to convince yourself that the arrow between those groups is the one taking a vector bundle to its sheaf of endomorphisms.  There's a brief proof about a third of the way down p.143 of Milne's *Etale cohomology*.  So the exact sequence says that two vector bundles trivialise the same Azumaya algebra if they differ by an element of $H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$, that is, by the class of a line bundle.

Comment: Wait: "two vector bundles trivialise the same Azumaya algebra if they differ by an element of $H^1(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$, that is, by the class of a line bundle." how do you conclude this? This is only an exact sequence of pointed sets.

Comment: Timo -- you're right, there's a bit more to say here, and it's not obvious that my answer is correct.  Unfortunately I am travelling and don't have the right reference to hand.  The usual thing in this situation is to wave one's hands and say "by twisting".  I believe Serre goes through the argument in some detail in the chapter on non-Abelian cohomology in "Cohomologie Galoisienne".

Comment: Yes, thank you. In fact, I just looked into "Coh. Gal." before reading your comment. ;-) It seems to follow from p. 50, Section 5.4 Corollary 1. I have to check it.

Comment: resp. p. 54, Section 5.7, Proposition 42.

One also has to check that this result transfers from group cohomology to (Cech) etale cohomology.